# Are all verbal automorphisms inner power automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group, power-automorphism

Suppose $G$ is a group. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Wa}{Wa}\DeclareMathOperator{\Tame}{Tame}\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$

Lets call $\phi \in \Aut(G)$ verbal automorphism iff $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \{a_i\}_{i=0}^n \subset G, \{e_i\}_{i=0}^n \subset \{-1; 1\}$ such that $\forall t \in G$ $(\phi(t) = a_0t^{e_1}a_1…t^{e_n}a_n)$. 
One can easily see, that all the verbal automorphisms form a normal subgroup in $\Aut(G)$. Lets denote this subgroup as $Va(G)$. One can see, that sometimes $Va(G)$ is a proper subgroup: for example, $C_2 \times C_2$ has no nontrivial verbal automorphisms, but $\Aut(C_2 \times C_2)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. Also one can see that a subgroup is invariant under verbal automorphisms iff it is normal.

Lets call $\phi \in \Aut(G)$ inner power automorphism iff it is a composition of an inner automorphism and a universal power automorphism. It is easy to see, that all inner power automorphisms form a normal subgroup in $\Aut(G)$. Lets denote this subgroup as $Ip(G)$. One can also see that $Ip(G) \leq Va(G)$ (as $\forall \phi \in Ip(G) \exists a \in G, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall t \in G (\phi(t) = a^{-1}t^na$)) and that $Ip(G)$ is always isomorphic to a homomorphic image of $\frac{G}{Z(G)} \times C_{\exp(G)}$, where $\exp(G)$ is the exponent of $G$.

Is the statement $Va(G) = Ip(G)$ always true?

If $G$ is abelian, then it definitely is, as all verbal automorphisms of any abelian group are universal power automorphisms. If $G$ is complete then the statement is also true, as all automorphisms of a complete group are inner. However, I failed to find out anything other than that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am struggling to parse the statement "$\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \{a_i\}_{i=0}^n \subset G \{e_i\}_{i=0}^n \subset \{-1; 1\} \forall t \in G \phi(t) = a_0t^{e_1}a_1…t^{e_n}a_n$." I am pretty sure I have worked it out, but it really isn't clear.

Comment: (Also, "tame" automorphisms was classically used to mean automorphisms of a group $G=\langle S\rangle$ induced by automorphisms of the ambiant free group $F(S)$.)

Comment: I think the following automorphism of the free group $F(a, b, c)$ is a counter-example: $\phi: a\mapsto a^2b^{-1}$, $b\mapsto bab^{-1}$, $c\mapsto cb^2$. This automorphism certainly is not a word automorphism, but I don't have the time at the moment to think about the inner-automorphism bit.

Comment: (Also, there is a paper of Cohen, Metzler and Zimmerman, *What does a basis of F(a,b) look like?*, Math. Ann. (1981) which proves something *very* similar to what you are talking about, but for the free group on two generators.)

Comment: Is your definition of word automorphism missing commas? And a "such that" before the "for all"?

Comment: @user1729, thank you, for your reply, but unfortunately this automorphism does not seem to provide a counterexample to my statement. If an automorphism is not a word automorphism, then it is not an inner power automorphism either (that is the new name of automorphisms, that I used to call "tame" before). That is due to the fact, that $\forall \phi \in Ip(G) \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, a\in G$, such that $\phi(t) = a^{-1}t^na$ by its definition. That results in $Ip(G) \leq Wa(G)$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. What is a universal power automorphism?

Comment: @user1729, a nice definition of universal power automorphism and its basic properties can be found under this link: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Universal_power_automorphism

Comment: Okay, then I do not think this is true. In the free group on two generators I *think* all automorphisms are word automorphisms (by the above paper of Cohen, Metzler and Zimmerman), while $IP(F_2)=Inn(F_2)$.